# basic javascript- insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript

I am a new learner of JavaScript and I am following a guide online. Basically I am creating a very simple to do list.
I tried to follow the guide but it seems that I am doing something wrong. It doesn't add to-do items on the web page.

```js
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let ourList = document.getElementById("ourList");
ourForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addItem(ourfield.value);
});

function addItem(x) {
  let ouritem = `<li>${x}<button>delete</button></li>`;
  ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ouritem);
}
```

```html
<h1>TO-DO app</h1>
<form id="ourForm">
  <input id="ourField" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
  <button>add item</button>
</form>

<ul id="ourList">
  <li>hello<button>delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your form submission listener - case matters to computers, at least the better ones.

Comment: @roishamayev use the console (F12), it's very handy

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. The question has no value to anyone in the future.

Comment: @j08691 it is definitely not off-topic plus you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Line 26 you have a typo :

```
ourForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
HERE => addItem(ourfield.value);
});
```

Your variable is called "ourField" not "ourfield"

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. The question has no value to anyone in the future.

Comment: Under the question's tags click the close link and you'll see the reasons.